# change variable value in event handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change my `gaTop` var in my `functiontest` but I don't understand why it doesn't work

```
var gaTop = 0;

functionTest = function(callback)
{
    $('html').on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e)
    {
        var delta = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail);

        if (delta < 0)
        {
            var gaTop = -100;
        }
        else if (delta > 0)
        {
            var gaTop = +100;
        }

        console.log(gaTop);

        callback(gaTop);
    });
}

functionTest(function(e)
{
    console.log(gaTop);
});
```

Comment: your declaring and initializing gaTop in every block and you are not using ga.

Comment: You have to make gaTop as a global variable or declare it in such a scope where both function can access it

Comment: i finally find the solution :

Answer (score 1):

As reference: [Declaring vs Initializing a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714434/declaring-vs-initializing-a-variable)

```
var ga = 0;
var gaTop = null;
functionTest = function(callback) {
$('html').on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
  var delta = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail);
  if (delta < 0) {
    gaTop = -100;
  } 
  else if (delta > 0) {
    gaTop = 100;
  }
  console.log(gaTop);
  callback(gaTop);

});
}
functionTest(function(e) {
 console.log(gaTop);
});
```

Comment: i'm sorry i did a mistake, my var ga should be gaTop. But the console.log(gaTop) always return 0

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variable at top before assign the value. otherwise it won't set, you are creating new variable and set the value in both if and else part that is the cause of issue.

```
var gaTop = null;
 if (delta < 0) {
     gaTop = -100;
  } 
  else if (delta > 0) {
    gaTop = +100;
  }
```

Comment: i'm sorry i did a mistake, my var ga should be gaTop. But the console.log(gaTop) always return 0

Comment: debug and verify the delta value in on mousewheel event

Answer (score 0):

its finally working, thanks for your help !

```
var gaTop = 0;

            functionTest = function(callback) {
            $('html').on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
              var delta = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail);
              if (delta < 0) {
                gaTop = gaTop -100;
              } 
              else if (delta > 0) {
                gaTop = gaTop +100;
              }
              callback(gaTop);

            });
            }
            functionTest(function(e) {
             console.log(gaTop);
            });
```