# What does it mean to initialize a variable in JavaScript 5?

Tags: javascript, initialization

I am required to initialize a variable in JavaScript 5. The exact instructions are "Declare a variable `chameleon` and initialize it to the string "lizard"."

Comment: the same as "*assign initial value*".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and try to do the work. This is **extremely** basic, and will be covered.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
var chameleon = "lizard";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var chameleon ="lizard";
```

Follow these links for further details

[Clear explanation on declaration and initialization of javascript variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714434/declaring-vs-initializing-a-variable)

[Use full link for learning and testing javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)